# flutter show error：“Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height”

Tags: flutter, height, swipe

this code show error "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height"

Container set hight is ok,but Is there an adaptive height solution?

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 50,
              child: Swiper(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text(index.toString());
                  },
                  itemCount: 5),
            )
          ],
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Expanded:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Swiper(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text(index.toString());
              },
              itemCount: 5),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```